# Add logo to vlc video Raspberry

Tags: raspberry-pi, vlc-media-player, raspbian

I try to set the crop function

- Raspberry Pi OS 11 (bullseye)
- vlc 3.VLC media player 3.0.16 Vetinari (revision 1.0.6-1682-g88158c836)
- Raspberry PI 3b+

```
cvlc -f --crop=16:9 --video-filter=croppadd{cropbottom=0,cropright=0,croptop=0,cropleft=0} /home/pi/Desktop/video/MSC-00001.mp4 --sub-source logo --logo-file /home/pi/Desktop/logo/plogo-tv.png --logo-position 10 --no-osd
```

but it doesn't appear.
but if I click ALT + C and then ALT + F after play it works and the logo appear...
why?

thanks

Comment: First of all, your cropping doesn't make too much sense. It throws a magnitude of errors on my setup. Why would you even crop zero pixels from each side? Second, you could check the keybindings in `Tools -> Preferences -> Hotkeys`. `Alt+C` and `Alt+F` are shortcuts for cropping one pixel. Another indication that your cropping is wrong.

Comment: @mashuptwice thanks, but I try alla configurations and with or without `--video-filter=croppadd{cropbottom=0,cropright=0,croptop=0,cropleft=0}` the only mode to make the logo visible is press `Alt+C` and `Alt+F` after the video play. I don't understand the problem. can you help me? thanks

Comment: since you need to crop one pixel from the right of the video by pressing `Alt+F` and one pixel from the bottom with `Alt+C` to get the video to play, you might want to alter your command to crop one pixel from the bottom and one pixel from the right. You could do that by setting the appropriate amount of pixels in your `filter=` section as following: `cvlc -f --crop=16:9 --video-filter=croppadd{cropbottom=1,cropright=1,croptop=0,cropleft=0} /home/pi/Desktop/video/MSC-00001.mp4 --sub-source logo --logo-file /home/pi/Desktop/logo/plogo-tv.png --logo-position 10 --no-osd`

Comment: I try `cvlc -f --crop=16:9 --video-filter=croppadd{cropbottom=1,cropright=1,croptop=0,cropleft=0} /home/pi/Desktop/video/MSC-00001.mp4 --sub-source logo --logo-file /home/pi/Desktop/logo/plogo-tv.png --logo-position 10 --no-osd --log-verbose 1` but I have a lot of errors as `chain filter error: Too high level of recursion (3)` and `main filter error: Failed to create video filter 'croppaddcropleft=0'` so the video start without logo and as before If I click Alt+c & Alt+f the logo appear in position. why??? Thanks

Comment: Well, I think I've found the solution: You simply need to put the arguments in quotes: `cvlc -f "--crop=16:9" "--video-filter=croppadd{cropbottom=1,cropright=1,croptop=0,cropleft=0}" /home/pi/Desktop/video/MSC-00001.mp4 --sub-source logo --logo-file /home/pi/Desktop/logo/plogo-tv.png --logo-position 10 --no-osd`

Please confirm that this also works on your end.

Comment: No, I'm sorry. 
`croppadd filter error: Unknown input chroma MMAL`
`chain filter error: Too high level of recursion (3)`
`mmal_codec filter error: Failed to commit format for output port vc.ril.isp:out:0(OPQV) (status=3 EINVAL)`

Comment: And the screen is black. If I try `cvlc -f "--crop=16:9" /home/pi/Desktop/video/MSC-00001.mp4 --sub-source logo --logo-file /home/pi/Desktop/logo/plogo-tv.png --logo-position 10 --no-osd` without video filter it works, but without logo

Comment: Maybe can be helpful, I try to deactivate KMS in raspberry, and the "trick" ALT+c and ALT+f doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I install Raspberry Pi OS (Legacy) with desktop, I enable FKMS and all works without any problem on my Raspberry 3b+. So the problem is the FKMS is not possible to enable in Debian version: 11 (bullseye). At now there are no problem with the logo and there are not dropped frames.
So the solution at now is enable the FKMS.
Thanks